# Cannot pass tweet_mode = 'extended' parameter to API in twitteR's searchTwitter function

Tags: r, twitter

I have been pulling tweets using the twitteR package's searchTwitter function but I see that many are truncated. Looking into this, I found that there is a parameter, tweet_mode = 'extended', that can be passed to the API to prevent truncation. This is described on their forums here:

https://twittercommunity.com/t/retrieve-full-tweet-when-truncated-non-retweet/75542/8

The documentation for this function says that additional parameters to GET can be passed as additional ellipsis arguments. Here's the link:

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/twitteR/versions/1.1.9/topics/searchTwitter

However, when I try this, the following error happens:

```
tweets <- searchTwitter("somesearchtext", n = 10, lang = "en", 
tweet_mode='extended')
Error in tw_from_response(out, ...) : 
  unused argument (tweet_mode = "extended")
```

Have any of you figured this out or found a workaround? I've spent quite some time searching this and cannot find any answers for why this doesn't work in the twitteR package.

I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the source code for [`searchTwitter()`](https://github.com/geoffjentry/twitteR/blob/master/R/search.R) there doesn't appear to be a parameter for `tweet_mode`.

However, you should note that the library `twitteR` has [been deprecated](https://github.com/geoffjentry/twitteR) in favour of [`rtweet`](https://github.com/mkearney/rtweet)

From the Github readme:

> This is the start of a relatively leisurely deprecation period for twitteR, in favor of using rtweet. Please start looking to switch over to that package. If you have any questions contact myself or @mkearney

---

The `search_tweets` function in `rtweet` passes further arguments to the Twitter API through the `...`

In this case there is the argument `full_text` (that [defaults to TRUE](https://github.com/mkearney/rtweet/blob/d81527588f578cbe984af7a29235503ca66b5a24/R/search.R#L351)). When this is set to TRUE it sets the `tweet_mode` parameter for the Twitter API to 'extended'. So you should be seeing the extended tweets by default

The source code for `search_tweets` shows the other params you can pass in

https://github.com/mkearney/rtweet/blob/d81527588f578cbe984af7a29235503ca66b5a24/R/search.R#L456

```
if (full_text) {
    full_text <- "extended"
} else {
    full_text <- NULL
}
## make params list
params <- list(q = q,
            result_type = type,
            count = 100,
            max_id = max_id,
            tweet_mode = full_text,
            geocode = geocode,
             ...)
## make url
url <- make_url(
    query = query,
    param = params)
```

so your search function should just work as-is

```
library(rtweet)

rt <- search_tweets("data science", n = 1000)
```

Comment: Wow, I don't know how I didn't find any mention of that. Thank you!

Just to clarify, it sets tweet_mode to extended automatically?

Comment: @MaxHeadroom yes I believe so - [the function definition](https://github.com/mkearney/rtweet/blob/d81527588f578cbe984af7a29235503ca66b5a24/R/search.R#L351) sets it to TRUE

Comment: @MaxHeadroom - just beware, what's in the github repo is all the latest development code and may not be exactly what's uploaded on CRAN; so worth double-checking your results.